# How to change shortcut for snap to view?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

When I hold  <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> and pan/orbit and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> it snaps the view to front,right etc.

Is there a way to change that hotkey to <kbd>Shift</kbd> so that when I hold <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> I will snap to the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very bottom of this image you can see where the shortcut can be changed in *User Prefs → Keymap.*
I searched "MM" (middle mouse) by *Key-Binding* to find it more easily.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't let me to change it but thank's alot, i was searching about an hour for this ;)

Comment: @Tasos I was able to change it after I expanded its tab. Fsr Blender collapses a bunch of tabs right after it gets changed but Shift did work for snapping the view after I changed them.

Comment: Finally got this worked, Thank's alot HISEROD !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this since <kbd>Alt</kbd> won't work with my tablet and *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* setup.

It took me a while to figure out but that seems to work like a charm.

To clarify, expanding the relevant tabs — *Rotate View* and then *Axis Snap* — and clicking <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> seen there, does give you a chance to change it; into <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> in my case.

[image: in Preferences under Keymap 3D View]

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/177767)